# Can I make a character carry an object in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is probably a very simple question, but is it possible to make a character carry an object in Unity 2D? I can make an object move at the same speed as the player, and I can make the player object flip from side to side. However, when the player moves onto one side, the object that I want the player to be facing obviously does not move with it. I could not find much code for mirror imaging, so I first tried teleporting the character using the transform. position command like so:

```
if (stHorizontalInput > 0.01f)
        {
            float stHorizontalOutput1 = stHorizontalInput * spede * Time.deltaTime;
            float stVerticalOutput1 = stVerticalInput * spede * Time.deltaTime;
            while (stHorizontalOutput1  < 10f)
            {
                transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(stHorizontalOutput1, stVerticalOutput1, 0);
            }
        }
```

However, this did in fact not work. At first, the object visibly moved, and quickly too, and I thought that a simple while loop would solve the issue of the object moving too far too fast, and way further than I needed it to, but with a while loop added as shown to prevent moving too far, the object would not move at all. I cannot make the object and the player one asset because the object needs to have a specific function that the player cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Still learning more about unity, but I think from a scripting perspective you should be able to "attach" your object to your character with something like this.

```
GameObject specialObject;
GameObject Character;
void SomeFunction()
{
specialObject. transform. position 
= 
Character. transform. position;
}
```

You can play with the offsets to get it placed correctly on the hand.
Might need a ifLeft == true or something to adjust the offset on flips.

This Unity learning guide talks about doing this with the camera. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/1-3-make-the-camera-follow-the-vehicle-with-variables.

I imagine you can do very similar for your character and object in the 2D view.